# SSRS 2010 - Create reports based on each multiple parameter value. So that each parameter value begins on a new page.

Tags: reporting-services

I have a SSRS report having a table based on multiple value parameters. For the parameter values I have a list of Partner IDs. I would like to export the report to a pdf and print it so that each Partner ID starts from a new page.

After adding the multiple value parameter, my report is displaying data for each Partner ID but they get nested under one another.

Any suggestions? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Insert LIST.
Past your report in LIST.
Go to rows group properties for LIST.
click Page Breaks then tick the box "Between Each instance Of The Group"
- should be sorted.